# How can get elements from .jsp file using java without servlets

Tags: java, jsp, intellij-idea, selenide

I have a "myData.jsp" in my Java project like this:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Book Query</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Another E-Bookstore</h1>
  <h3>Choose Author(s):</h3>
  <form method="get">
    <input type="checkbox" name="author" value="Tan Ah Teck">Tan
    <input type="checkbox" name="author" value="Mohd Ali">Ali
    <input type="checkbox" name="author" value="Kumar">Kumar
    <input type="submit" value="Query">
  </form>
```

How can I get for example "title" value from this jsp file using java

Comment: Read the **.jsp** file into a single string object: `String jspString = new java.util.Scanner(new File("myData.jsp")).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();` (this will need to be wrapped within a try/catch for a *java.io.FileNotFoundException*). To get the title from between the title tags: `String title = jspString.substring(jspString.indexOf("<title>") + 7, jspString.indexOf("</title>"));`.

Comment: There's no "title" value in the JSP. How do you want to get it?